# Print in a new terminal opened with popen()

Tags: c, terminal, popen

I want to open a new terminal and then print something in there. The following program's output is:

Successfully Opened
The fputs returned 1.

But nothing is printed in the new terminal. Any idea what I do wrong?
Thank you

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    FILE *fp;
    int rv;

    fp = popen("gnome-terminal&", "w");
    sleep(5);
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        puts("Error opening");
    }
    else
    {
        puts("Successfully Opened");
        rv = fputs("New Terminal Successfully Opened", fp);
        printf("The fputs returned %d.\n",rv);
        pclose(fp);

    }
    sleep(5);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: That is not possible the way you do it, `printf();` will print in the same terminal where you execute the program, what are you trying to do? I saw your previous question, and I am really curious, I would actually like to help you to see if it could be achieved, but I need to know what are you trying to do. Oh, and with `popen()` you don't need `&`, it will call `fork()`.

Comment: You will have to get the `/dev/pts/n` (where `n` is an integer) of the newly-opened terminal and print to it. I am not entirely sure how to do that though, and the method will probably vary with platform. Also, [`popen(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) behaves differently than what you're expecting from it.

Comment: @iharob Thank you for you help. It's for a project in one off my courses. I've to extend the uncompleted, given, functions of a tiny os that runs on simple virtual machine. This tinyos supports 1 to 4 terminals. The user can have simultaneous interaction with the tinyos via each the terminal and execute a couple of simple programs that the tinyos supports. I want open 1-4 terminals before executing the tinyos and then direct the tinyos to read from and write to them. This program is for testing the read/write to the terminal.

Comment: @iharob Yes you are right, it works also without the &. I don't expect printf to print in the new terminal but fputs("New Terminal Successfully Opened", fp); Why this doesn't work?

Comment: because `fputs()` is writing to the `stdin` of the new process, which is not the `gnome-terminal` when you use the `&`, you can do that, but not that way. `gnome-terminal` is just a terminal emulator, so your first idea will not work, can you communicate with through yahoo messenger for example, I speak spanish. iharob@yahoo.com

Comment: @iharob Actually, `fputs` writes to a file descriptor `fp` he is passing. I'm assuming his example isn't working because he's writing to the `fp`'s `stdin`, not `stdout`. I wonder if writing `echo "New Terminal Successfully Opened"\n` would work (I'm unable to test it now)?

Comment: @destielstarship `fp` is not a file descriptor, and `popen` returns an I/O stream which writes to the standard input of the executed command. And i don't think it would work.

Comment: @iharob Well, yes it's a file stream, but `popen(3)` returns a `FILE*`, which is essentially a C abstraction for a fd. So, it should behave like any other `FILE` object/value.

Comment: @destielstarship I will google /dev/pts/ to figure out what's in there thanks. I also expected to use the value returned from the popen as a file descriptor

Comment: @iharob I have added you on yahoo messenger. I only speak greek and english. Thank you anyway for the help